# how to get creation date of a lvm snapshot?

Tags: lvm

Is there some way to get the date that an lvm snapshot was created?

`lvs --version
  LVM version:     2.02.66(2) (2010-05-20)`

Neither lvdisplay nor lvs provides this information. Looking through the man pages on these two commands there are not any options to give it. For that matter, is there a way to get the creation date of any logical volume?

Here is what I see when I run lvdisplay:

`~# id; lvdisplay vol0/m0000700.20150108
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vol0/m0000700.20150108
  VG Name                vol0
  LV UUID                ShKkjV-tbL4-SjKv-dfA4-7fft-2Pl1-UKThSs
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV snapshot status     active destination for /dev/vol0/m0000700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                109.05 GiB
  Current LE             27918
  COW-table size         110.00 GiB
  COW-table LE           28160
  Allocated to snapshot  26.12% 
  Snapshot chunk size    4.00 KiB
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:28`

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way to get the creation date of any logical volume?

run command

```
sudo lvdisplay
```

output will be

```
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg/vol
  LV Name                vol
  VG Name                vg
  LV UUID                9M1Hxw-X4bN-t7t4-7auG-qOnb-WHh1-WJVcne
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time name, 2015-08-20 11:42:33 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                18.62 GiB
  Current LE             4768
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0
```

you can see `LV Creation host, time`

Comment: what version of lvdisplay to do you have? my version does not contain these fields:

Comment: LVM version:     2.02.98(2) (2012-10-15)    Library version: 1.02.77 (2012-10-15)   Driver version:  4.27.0

Comment: your version is about 2 years newer than mine, and i ran across something online saying that the older version didn't provide this information. ... I wonder if there's another way to get it?